# SQLite database list view

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, cursor

I have created a database with a cursor. I want to show it in a list view. This is my Activity file:

```
package com.ucas.course;

import java.util.List;

import org.w3c.dom.Comment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SQLView extends ListActivity {

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_example);
        UCAS info = new UCAS(this);
        info.open();
        String values = info.getData();
        info.close();
        AString[] columns = new String[] {UCAS.KEY_UNIVERSITY};
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name_entry, R.id.number_entry };
        startManagingCursor(c);
        SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.sqlview, c, columns, to);
        this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);

 }



}
```

AT the moment there are no error apart from one cursor error "invalid statement in fillWindow()", I don't know if that has something to do with my issue but when I start the activity I just get a blank screen

```
public Cursor getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_UNIVERSITY, KEY_OFFER};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);


    return c;
}
```

Comment: number of itmes in "columns" and "to" must be equal! Also cursor should contain "_id" column (I assume that this is your KEY_ROWID column).

Comment: I've changed them to this String[] columns = new String[] {UCAS.KEY_ROWID,UCAS.KEY_UNIVERSITY, UCAS.KEY_OFFER};
         int[] to = new int[] { R.id.KEY_ROWID, R.id.KEY_UNIVERSITY, R.id.KEY_OFFER}; I assume that's what you meant but I still get the error and nothing shows

Answer (score 1):

Lists can and in your case should use cursors to back their data. There's no reason for you to build a result string to hold your query values. You can pass the cursor directly to the adapter.

```
public String getData() {
     String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_UNIVERSITY, 
         KEY_COURSE, KEY_UCAS, KEY_SATISFACTION, KEY_EMPLOYED, 
         KEY_OFFER, KEY_OTHER};

     Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, 
         columns, null, null, null, null, null);

     return c;

}
```

Once you have the cursor, bind it to the ListActivity using a SimpleCursorAdapter.

Comment: hi thanks that was usefull but now i have hit another wall i've edited the post above with more infomation and my new script

Answer (score 0):

there is small change to your function

```
    public String getData() {
     String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_UNIVERSITY, 
         KEY_COURSE, KEY_UCAS, KEY_SATISFACTION, KEY_EMPLOYED, 
         KEY_OFFER, KEY_OTHER};

     Cursor c = mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, 
         columns, null, null, null, null, null);

     return c;

}
```

Comment: in onDestroy method of your activity close the cursor

Comment: how do I close the cursor? sorry i'm new to this stuff

Comment: ((CursorAdapter) this.getListAdapter()).getCursor().close();

Comment: thats not changed anything sorry. could have somthing to do with my XML's